# Font Awsome Offline doesnt work correctly

Tags: font-awesome

I wanted to use fontawsome but offline not with the cdn.So I downloaded the necesary files , made the correct refference in my html about the font awsome css file and when I try something for example like this in my html

```
<i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

it works correctly and it displays a star.However what I want to do is try to use that star in my css code not my html code, so what I did was

```
.rating label:before{
   content: '\f005';
    font-family: fontAwesome;
}
```

However that way it doesnt load the star corectly but it loads a curupted symbol instead, it works fine with the cdn though any help?

Comment: You're discussing two problems and the title may not ask for what you want. Can you pls. make clear if (1) your problem is using FA offline (so that even the simple i-tag doesn't work) or (2) using pseudo-elements? Are using FA4 or FA5?

Comment: Th problem is using pseudo elements with bootstrap offline.Using pseudo  elements with bootstrap online works fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I assume you're using FA4. I think there might be a problem with the folder-structure not being replicated as required on your localhost. Can you pls. check the location of a few files?  (1) font-awesome.min.css  (2) fontawesome-webfont.woff.